# Explain: "The 'B' in 'Benoît B. Mandelbrot' stands for 'Benoît B. Mandelbrot'."

Tags: geometry, math-history

> "The 'B' in 'Benoît B. Mandelbrot' stands for 'Benoît B. Mandelbrot'."

We had an extra credit quiz involving people, and I didn't quite get this one.

I know what the Mandelbrot set is but I don't know anything else, all I know is that it looks weird and sometimes when I zoom in it looks like the same image.

Can someone explain the significance of this statement?

Comment: May be it is exactly what you say for the set: zooming in the name, you find... the name itself!

Comment: called self similarity

Comment: It is like "I have found an interesting anagram of Banach Tarski. It is Banach Tarski Banach Tarski".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, it's about self similarity and also recursion. Another example is GNU - GNU is Not Unix (the G in GNU stands for GNU).